# Java size of Long and String objects

Tags: java, memory

[Here](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2077496/testing-debugging/java-tip-130--do-you-know-your-data-size-.html), the author's tests say that `Integer` and `Long` objects occupy the same amount of memory, i.e., 16 bytes. However, when I run the exact code in an online Java compiler [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_java_online.php?PID=0Bw_CjBb95KQMTkVaQXpla0xmdjA), I get different results. A `Long` object seems to occupy 24 bytes.

Furthermore, the author says an empty `String` object occupies 40 bytes memory. However, the online compiler says it occupies 24 bytes.

Why could this be happening? Has there been an update to the Java compiler?

**Note**: The author does note that their results are based on Sun's JDK 1.3.1 for Windows and warns that they may change.

Comment: Authors sometimes make mistakes.  In the case of String, it was definitely updated, sometime mid to late Java 7.

Comment: Wow, I would not trust any article from 2002

Comment: Wish I could find a newer article :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The author clearly states:

> Note: The following results are based on Sun's JDK 1.3.1 for Windows. Due to what is and is not guaranteed by the Java language and JVM specifications, you cannot apply these specific results to other platforms or other Java implementations.

Comment: Hey! Have this in my copy/paste clipboard... Well, you were faster.

Comment: Good to confirm that that was the issue and not anything else. Thanks!